# Is it possible to override an apps built-in activity with your own?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Specifically, is it possible for me to override the email view in gmail, so that when the user clicks on an email in their inbox it will ask them whether they want to open the email in gmail or my app?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the gmail app opens the email. It looks to me like it gets opened in a fragment, but you can check the source. Check [here](http://source.android.com/) how to get it. I think the gmail app source should be included. If they open it in a separate Activity with an IntentFilter, then you can register your own activity for it. I think your chances are not that good, though...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you just need to find the right category to
 add in manifest besides LAUNCHER  and MAIN.

It could be Catergory.EMAIL, but do not know.

Would like to search it for you but am currently on my phone which isnt suited for googling around.

Edit:

Nevermimd, misread your question :-)